# How to skip a landing page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a landing page that is like a large scrolling infographic.  I need to implement a "skip this next time" checkbox so that returning users that authenticate can skip having to see it everytime they visit the site.

The landing page is a static page served by the `static_controller.rb`:

```
def landing
  if cookies[:skip_landing]
      redirect_to home_url
  else
    if params[:skip_landing]
      cookies.permanent[:skip_landing] = true
    end
  end
end
```

This mostly works as I think it should.  It sets the `cookie[:skip_landing]` to **true**.  However, when I clear that cookie, I can't get back to the landing page.  I am redirected to the home page, which should only be true if the cookie were set.  Somehow, the cookie is being reset

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. I've debugged for around 10mins and then realised that `cookies[:skip_landing]` is actually a String.

So even if you have `cookies[:skip_landing] = 'false'`, it `if cookies[:skip_landing]` would still be seen as true since only `nil` and `false` in ruby is false.

You may try this:

```
if cookies[:skip_landing] == '1'
  redirect_to home_url
elsif params[:skip_landing]
  cookies.permanent[:skip_landing] = '1'
end
```

end